# Creating menus from terms

Tags: views, 7, blocks

i want to make a complicated tabs block for terms  (i usually views and quick tabs for this and it works great) . in this block i want a main tabs bar when i click on one of it it shows the content that have that term or any of its chlidren term, also i want a second tabs bar to show, if the main term have any children term and put in that bar the lev.1 children for the main term ,so if i click on it it shows the term's content and any of its children term content to ,i hope i described it well ,  check the image for more understanding

my question is : is that possible using views or any other modules or should i create my own module -which i allready started creating but its taking a long time - ??

thanks in advance

[image: a tabs block structure]

Comment: Please give the question a more useful title.

Comment: I took a try at a better title.  Edit it if this isn't what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think you want the [Taxonomy Menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module:

> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with Views
> - Integrate with Pathauto: use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules

However, the last time I did this, I wrote my own module.  Essentially, I wired up taxonomy hooks to call [`menu_link_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) for new terms, and [`menu_link_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_link_delete/7) when terms were deleted.  This is a rather complicated process.  If you go this route, I would study the submit handlers for the menu module to see how everything works.  You also need to study the taxonomy API to see how to walk trees when you have a hierarchical vocabulary.

Comment: first thanks for the answer , Well , yes and No ,i want the menu Integrate with Views , but to be used as a filter to the content and works with ajax